# What arguments are available for the Python Tk() constructor?

Tags: python, constructor, tkinter, arguments, tk-toolkit

I'm trying to make a python tkinter application and I'm having a lot of trouble finding a list of what arguments are available for creating a `Tk` object.

example:

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk(<args>)
root.mainloop()
```

Where can I find a full list of the arguments available?

For example I know I can give the window a title after it is already created by saying `root.title("title")`, but can I give the window a title in the constructor directly?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html#Tkinter.Tk

Comment: @tjwrona1992 The answer to your question is in the documentation...

Comment: `dir()` is a good way to see methods.

Comment: This is a bad question because it simply asks to replicate the information already present in the library in question's documentation page, which is easily accessible from wherever you downloaded that package.

Comment: I know it is in the documentation, but googling the words "Tk" and "arguments" doesn't get you very far because you get flooded with a massive amount of useless information since there are so many articles related to Tk.  Searching for the correct spot in the documentation becomes very difficult unless you already know where it is which is why I asked this question.

Comment: In fact most questions asked about any language on stack overflow have answers in the "documentation"...  That doesn't make them bad questions.

Comment: Perhaps the reason for downvotes is because you didn't *show* what research you did. We can't read your mind, we have no way of knowing that you searched through documentation, or what documentation you searched through. If you ask a fundamental question that's covered in some documentation, we must assume you haven't read the documentation or tried to read the documentation, or used the `dir` or `help` commands, unless you tell us otherwise.

Comment: _"Please save your downvotes for people who actually deserve them"_ - this is a misunderstanding on your part. Downvotes aren't for _people_. The votes aren't a criticism of you, but simply a relative assessment of the usefulness of the _question_. Don't take it personally. You might want to read this: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/7432

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean to come off as grumpy... I was just frustrated from not finding the information I was looking for.  But as for the topic discussing when and how someone should post a question on stack overflow I have to say I completely disagree with the accepted answer.  If that were true it would completely defeat the purpose of SO.  I do however agree with this response: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261598/3964397

Comment: I am looking for what these arguments actually mean, for which I did search, but found nothing yet. I wonder if to make a new question, or rather to browse the source code.

Comment: @comodoro, That's exactly what I mean! These arguments clearly are not documented well enough... It seems people got a little downvote happy on this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used the documentation, which can be accessed via IDLE, Is this what you looking for?

[image]

Comment: Yes that is more of what I am looking for.  So there is no way to set the title of the window directly from the constructor?  I'm basically wondering if there is a way to set many of the basic attributes in one line.

Comment: You could possibly wrap the creation of the tk object in class or a function and then call this function with arguments that you want to set. E.g. Createtk('WindowName')

Comment: I'm using notepad++ so I don't get information like that when I type in functions.  After seeing this I might start using IDLE instead.

Comment: But basically what your saying is there's no way directly through the constructor?  It just seems strange because all of the widgets in tkinter seem to have many of the options available straight through the constructor.

Comment: Yes seems like you cannot set the title via the constructor